# OpenJDK and Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, java

This is more of a general question about OpenJDK and packages being removed.

I am removing `libatk-wrapper-java`. However when I use apt-get to remove it, it says `openjdk-7-jre` will also be removed. My question is, I am still able to use the java command successfully even after `openjdk-7-jre` was removed, how is this possible?

Comment: You'll might get more help with this at http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to find out where the Java command that's being used is located:

```
which java
```

Then, use `ls -l` to find out if that's a symlink, and if so, where it points. (There's a good chance it will point to something in `/etc/alternatives`, at least that's what it does on my system.)

Keep using `ls -l` to follow the links until you find the real binary that is being run.

Then, use this to find out what package owns the binary:

```
dpkg -S $PATH_TO_JAVA_BINARY
```

On my machine, this process looks like this:

```
AWS:~$ which java
/usr/bin/java
AWS:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Jul 30 22:47 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java*
AWS:~$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 Jul 30 22:47 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java*
AWS:~$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java
openjdk-6-jre-headless: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java
```

This tells me that the package `openjdk-6-jre-headless` is installed, and that's what owns the Java binary that is run when I type `java` at the command prompt. (There still might be one or more other JVM's on your system, though. This is only telling me which one will be the default.)

This might not be the fastest way to answer your question, but it will hopefully help you understand your system setup a little better.

Comment: This helps clear things up, thanks! Now the question is, why is it still there when it was supposed to be removed when I was removing libatk-wrapper-java.

Comment: The answer to that question will depend on what this procedure tells you. Maybe you will find that there was another package providing Java in addition to the one that has been removed. Or, maybe the removal of `openjdk-7-jre` never got completed for some reason.

Comment: Your edit helped answer my question about openjdk-6-jre-headless still being there. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if `openjdk-6-jre-headless` is still there for you. It is there on my system because that's what I installed in the first place. You will have to run these commands on your own system to find out if it's there for you. (If you meant that you did this already, then great!)

Answer (score 0):

do you have any other JDK's installed?
i'm using LINUx as-well and it came with openjdk-6. is that the case with you?
check in /usr/share/doc/openjdk-6-jre

Comment: I only have that one JDK installed but it seems that the openjdk-6-jre-headless version was not deleted.